# Error code 100 using fitdist in the fitdistrplus package for pois and nbinom

Tags: r, distribution, fitdistrplus

I am trying to fit a distribution to my data (`ssdist`; `ssi` is the values), however I keep getting thrown the error code below, and I have no idea why. Notably, the error is only thrown for `pois` and `nbinom` which are the distributions that I think might fit the data best.

> Error in fitdistrplus::fitdist(ss$ssi[ss$name == s], distr = "nbinom")
> :    the function mle failed to estimate the parameters,
> with the error code 100

Here is my code:

```
ssdist <- read_excel(here("Data/Raw/ssdist.xlsx")) %>%
  verify(has_all_names("name", "ssi")) %>% 
  assert(name) %>% 
  assert(is.numeric, ssi)

library(fitdistrplus)

par0 <- par(mfrow = c(3,2))
for(s in unique(ssdist$name)) {
  fitdistrplus::descdist(ss$ssi[ss$name == s], discrete = TRUE)
  title(sub = s)
}
par(par0)
```

**This is the code block giving me issues**

```
    par0 <- par(mfrow = c(2,2))
for(s in unique(ssdist$name)) {
  f <- fitdistrplus::fitdist(ss$ssi[ss$name == s], distr = "nbinom")
  fitdistrplus::cdfcomp(f, main = "Cumulative distribution: Data vs. theoretical")
  title(sub = s)
  mtext(side = 3, line = 0,
        text = paste0("p-value: ", round(fitdistrplus::gofstat(f)$chisqpvalue, 4)))
}
par(par0)
```

Here is a link to my data (I was unsure how to post it here): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B-9sygnfDd8rUjyN3ZO6DwpvMO95FLMi02RlKpDC7Ig/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your data contains non-integer numbers. How can the underlying distribution be Poisson or negative binomial? Surely these require integer data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

Lot's of problems here. The error you're getting is just the tip of the iceberg, so to speak.

The default method in `fitdist(...)` is maximum likelihood estimation (mle). `fitdist(...)` uses the `optim(...)` function to do this (actually to minimize the negative log likelihood, which amounts to the same thing). This error is coming from `optim(...)` and means the minimization failed. It's pretty common when either the choice of distribution is poor, or the initial values for the distribution parameters are poorly chosen. In your case it's a bit of both.

Your data has non-integer values. The negative binomial distribution has support on the positive integers (incl 0), so by definition the probability density for non-integer x is 0. If you read the documentation on `dnbinom(...)` you'll see that.

A second problem is that you data has very long tails:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
setDT(ss)
ggplot(ss, aes(x=ssi)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=name), color='grey80') + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=2*(0:5))+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide='none')+
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

so it's doubtful that any distribution in the exponential family would provide an adequate fit. One possibility is log normal, but this distribution has support on the positive reals, and your data has zeros.

Another possibility is the Weibull distribution:

```
get.params <- function(x) {
  start  <- list(shape=1, scale=1)
  f      <- fitdist(x, distr = dweibull, start=start, method='mge')
  return(c(as.list(f$estimate)))
}
params <- ss[, get.params(ssi), by=.(name)]
```

Which seems to do a decent job dealing with the long tails:

```
ss[params, c('shape', 'scale'):=.(i.shape, i.scale), on=.(name)]
setorder(ss, name, ssi)
ss[, sample:=quantile(ssi, probs = ppoints(.N)), by=.(name)]
ss[, theoretical:=qweibull(ppoints(.N), shape, scale), by=.(name)]
ss[, dens:=dweibull(ssi, shape, scale), by=.(name)]
ss[, smpl.CDF:=ecdf(ssi)(ssi), by=.(name)]
ss[, theor.CDF:=pweibull(ssi, shape, scale), by=.(name)]
ggplot(ss, aes(x=ssi))+
  geom_line(aes(y=theor.CDF, color=name))+
  geom_point(aes(y=smpl.CDF), shape=21)+
  scale_color_discrete(guide='none')+
  labs(title='CDF Plots')+
  facet_wrap(~name)
```

[image]

But even here you really should look at the q-q plots:

```
ggplot(ss, aes(x=theoretical, y=sample))+
  geom_point(aes(color=name))+
  geom_abline(color='blue', linetype='dashed')+
  scale_color_discrete(guide='none')+
  labs(title='QQ Plots')+
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

which really highlight the extreme tails. IMO the chi-sq gof metrics are pretty useless in this situation.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. This data I am working with is much different from what I used to work with so I have been struggling a lot. This helps to point me in the right direction.

Comment: One option I have is to remove the outlier site, which is the source for all data in the tail